# Django Rest Framework nested object serialization, depth >= 2

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am building an API with Django Rest Framework. I would like to POST a *takeoutOrder* JSON object like this:

```
{
    "takeoutOrderID": "001",
    "components": [
        {
            "name": "chicken",
            "componentID": 1
        },
        {
            "name": "beef",
            "componentID": 2
        },
        {
            "name": "rice",
            "componentID": 3
        },
        {
            "name": "carrot",
            "componentID": 4
        }
    ],
    "meals": [
        {
            "name": "chickenAndRice",
            "mealID": 00,
            "components": [1,3]
        },
        {
            "name": "kitchenSink",
            "mealID": 01,
            "components": [1,2,3,4]
        }
    ]
}
```

My **models** look like this:

```
class TakeoutOrder(models.Model):
    requestID = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/api/request/%s/" % self.requestID


class Meal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    mealID = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)
    takeoutOrder = models.ForeignKey(TakeoutOrder, related_name="meals")


class Component(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    componentID = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)
    takeoutOrder = models.ForeignKey(TakeoutOrder, related_name='components')
    meal = models.ForeignKey(Meal, related_name='components', null=True)
```

My **Serializers** look like this:

```
class ComponentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Component
        fields = ('name', 'componentID')

class MealSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    components = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Meal
        fields = ('name', 'mealID', 'components')

class TakeoutOrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    components = ComponentSerializer(many=True)
    meals = MealSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = TakeoutOrder
        fields = ('takeoutOrderID', 'components', 'meals')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        components_data = validated_data.pop('components')
        meals_data = validated_data.pop('meals')
        takeoutOrder = TakeoutOrder.objects.create(**validated_data)

        for meal_data in meals_data:
            Meal.objects.create(takeoutOrder=takeoutOrder, **meal_data)

        for component_data in components_data:
            Component.objects.create(takeoutOrder=takeoutOrder, **component_data)

        return takeoutOrder
```

When I try to post to the */takeoutOrder* endpoint with this setup I successfully create an object, however the meals' component arrays are empty (I believe this is because the components haven't yet been created when the Meals are created). Any thoughts on how to better write my serialization create() methods, or any other suggestions? I'm a little stuck.

Apologies in advance if there is another post answering this question, I looked for a while but couldn't find one.

Thanks!!

Comment: You want duplicate the components on database? because you are storing the primary key of meat in each component.

Comment: It's possible my models are incorrect, but I am trying to link the primary keys of components to each meal they are a part of. The serialization process needs to validate that, in fact, each component listed for the meal exists.

Answer (score 0):

First: I think the models was wrong.

**Because:** you will create multiple components, as all you need is an association.

Change the model **Component** :

```
class Component(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    componentID = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)
```

Add a new **Model**:

```
class MealComponent(models.Model):
    meal = models.ForeignKey(Meal)
    component = models.ForeignKey(Component)
```

and then:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    components_data = validated_data.pop('components')
    meals_data = validated_data.pop('meals')
    takeoutOrder = TakeoutOrder.objects.create(**validated_data)

    for component_data in components_data:
        Component.objects.create(**component_data)

    for meal_data in meals_data:
        meal_data.update({'takeoutOrder':takeoutOrder}
        meal = Meal.objects.create(**meal_data)
        meal_components = meal_data.pop('components')

        for meal_comp in meal_components:
            component = Component.objects.get(pk=meal_comp)
            MealComponent.objects.create(meal=meal,component=component)

    return takeoutOrder
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, I just tried your implementation and I still get empty _components[]_ arrays within **meals** in the response. The components don't seem to be stored to the DB yet.

Comment: i updated the answer, for clarify the answer, maybe now, can solve this.

Comment: That just about did it, @PauloPessoa. Thank you for the help! I'm going to follow up this post with the slightly modified solution that worked for me, but nice work!